# Login Screen ScrollView is not scrolling in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my login screen there are 5 entry's. I used scrollview but it is not scrolling. I have attached the sample code. Please anybody help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dh55ezCgUEnQgHnkLV3EjhzSZljTAs8c)

Answer (score 1):

> when I type any text to Entry one, keyboard hides Entry four and Entry five and it does not scroll.

Add `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan` attribute in your `Activity` like this :

```
[Activity(Label = "FloatingEntryApp", 
    Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
    Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
    WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan,
    MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

For more detail information about **AdjustPan**, you could read [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) :

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

### Update :

A simple solution, add a blank `Label` in you `LoginPage`, and use `Margin` to adjust the `ScrollView` height, then  you could  scrolling to entry four or five.

```
Label label = new Label
{
     Text = "   ",
     Margin = new Thickness(0, 200, 0, 0)
};

detailStack.Children.Add(label);
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGanj.gif).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @York Shen - MSFT. I have put  WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan, to my MainActivity but it still not working.

Comment: @Yogeshwaran, when you click Entry five, it still cant't be shown? What is the effect you want ?

Comment: When I type any text to entry one, two and three that time entry four and five hided by soft keyboard. The soft keyboard hides entry four and five and that time scrolling to entry four and five is not working.

Comment: @Yogeshwaran, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: We don't add any empty label to the login screen. It is not a proper way to achieve. scrolling happen only when the text is entered in the entry one otherwise scrolling should not happen

Comment: @Yogeshwaran, I have a solution that add a empty label, but only when the text is entered  in the entry   `ScrollView` can scroll, can you accept it ? When you didn't input something, the `scrollView` can't be scrolled.

Comment: Shen, No. please check my sample code. There are five entries where enter any text to entry one, entry two and entry three. Where entry four and entry five is hided by keyboard. Without hiding the keyboard and pressing back button fill all entries, that time scrolling is not working.

Comment: @Yogeshwaran, I think you need to detect the `keyboard`, when the keyboard is shown, you need to give your `ScrollView` a new height(the `screen height` - `keyboard height`) and update the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code, ScrollView is working properly but the content should fill in the screen then scrollview will work otherwise won't work

For example, Put Spacing="500" to that detailStack StackLayout Childrens then you can easily understand the problem.

I suggested you, use XAML for design and MVVM or Prism pattern

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Venkata Swamy Balaraju. We don't put any spacing to detail stack. My problem is when I type any text to Entry one, keyboard hides Entry four and Entry five and it does not scroll.